# Why does the text in word run over the indent marker (run into margin)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, text-formatting, alignment, margins

Why is my text in word suddenly not obeying the indent markers? It runs past the marker and into the margin. If I adjust the indent marker left or right, the edge of the paragraph does move with the marker - but always extends past it by the same amount.

I imagine there is a simple solution, but I cannot find which button to press!

I'm using Word 2007 in Print layout.

Example of problem text:
[image: Image: Example of problem text]

Dialogue boxes:
[image: Image: Dialogue boxes]

Update: The problem is present on every page: all paragraphs are running over their right indent marker.
Update: The issue also occurs with all fonts and styles. Uploaded new image showing text limits (Options > Advanced > Show Text Limits). [Fonts, Styles and Text Limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjqc1.jpg) The issue does not occur across all documents - I've created a new document and that is OK. I will leave this question open in case there is a solution that could help others. But if it is likely that I just had a one-off bad file, the question can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I don't know the problem. However, it looks sort of buggy to me. The ruler seems not to align with the 1.31cm margin you defined at "Mise en page" > "Extérieur".
You might want try to modifying those 1.31cm and see what happens.
As workaround - and in case this behavior concerns just this one file and is not consistently exhibited in others: consider copying all text into a newly created Word file. You seem not to have too much formatting, it should thus be simple. I've had Word having bugs which I could only solve by putting my text into a new file.